# Mysql INSERT statement in C

Tags: mysql, c, raspberry-pi, sql-insert

I'm going loopy here and cannot fix my problem.  I have looked at many supposed answer that do not fix my error.

I am trying to get temp and humidity data from a DHT11 sensor into a mysql database.  I can get the terminal to display the readings and it all works fine except I cannot get the data into the database.  There are no problems compiling the c code.  It just wont populate the database.

```
  char query[2000];
  MYSQL *conn;
  conn = mysql_init(NULL);
  mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "drewibbo", "monkeykangaroo", "temp_humidity", 0, NULL, 0);
  sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO readings(temp,humidity,date,time) VALUES(%d.%d,%d.%d,2015-02-18,00:00:00)",dht11_val[2],dht11_val[3],dht11_val[0],dht11_$
  mysql_query(conn, query);
  mysql_close(conn);
```

Thanks for any help that can be given.

Andy

Comment: Is the datatype for `temp` and `humidity` `float`? Also, `date` should be in `quotes`.

Comment: better to use `mysql_error(conn)` after `mysql_query(conn, query);` in order to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT query has wrong syntax, you need to put the date and the time into quotes, like.

```
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO readings(temp,humidity,date,time) VALUES(%d.%d,%d.%d,'2015-02-18','00:00:00')",dht11_val[2],dht11_val[3],dht11_val[0],dht11_ ...
```

Your query might have other issues, this is just one that I noticed. Just make your code report errors if they occur: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-error.html

Comment: This has answered my question.  I knew the community wouldn't let me down.  Thank you sooooo much. :D