# How to connect and insert record to mysql using c language?

Tags: mysql, c, database-connection, sql-insert

**Hello friends,**

My question is, can i connect mysql with c language?
And if connection is possible so how to insert record to mysql database.
Please give simple and small example.

If any query so comment please.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/ may be this help for you/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use the MySQL C Connector which your can find on their website: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Concerning your request regarding the example, a simple research would have helped you:
[Mysql INSERT statement in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602168/mysql-insert-statement-in-c)

Nothing beats the manual though: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-function-overview.html

EDIT:

Here is a simple example:

sql.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                   
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                  
#include <mysql/mysql.h>                                                                             

int main(void)                                                                                       
{                                                                                                    
  MYSQL *conn;                                                                                       

  if ((conn = mysql_init(NULL)) == NULL)                                                             
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not init DB\n");                                                 
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                  
  if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "user", "passwd", "dbname", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)             
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "DB Connection Error\n");                                                        
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                  
  if (mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO table_1 (test) VALUES ('Hello World')") != 0)                   
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "Query Failure\n");                                                              
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                  
  mysql_close(conn);                                                                                 
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                                               
}
```

`gcc sql.c -o sql -lmysqlclient`

Comment: Hello Ra'Jiska,  Thank you for your answer.